# Why does overflow result in 0?

Tags: d, integer-overflow

I've searched the docs but I can't find anything to explain this.

I have a D program:

```d
import std.stdio;
void main () {
  writeln(int.max);
  int a = 2;
  int b = 180;
  writeln(a^^b);
}
```

It writes:

```
2147483647
0
```

I overflowed `int`, but instead of getting junk or wrapping, I get `0`.

If I use `real` or `double`, obviously the output will be correct.

I wrote a program to experiment with this in C (not that C is D, but D compiles to native code and C is portable assembler, so they should be comparable):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main(void) {
  double i = pow(2, 128);
  int j    = (int) i;
  printf("int max:          %d\n", INT_MAX);
  printf("print dbl as int: %d\n", i);
  printf("cast dbl -> int:  %d\n", j);
  printf("double:           %f\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives:

```
int max:          2147483647
print dbl as int: -1254064128
cast dbl -> int:  -2147483648
double:           340282366920938463463374607431768211456.000000
```

The second and third lines line will rarely be the same thing twice, as I believe it's undefined behaviour, which is the point.

I know that D wants to be a better C, and a way to do this is to eliminate undefined behaviour.

But, if D is a systems programming language (it even has inline `asm`), why does D refuse to wrap on overflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It DID wrap on overflow. You just happened to try the family of cases that happen to wrap to zero. Try `3^^180`. I got -949019631. Just because a number happens to look pretty on screen doesn't mean it isn't garbage!

Consider that 2^^n == 1 << n. What happens when you shift a single bit left over and over and over again? Eventually, all the bits on the right become zero! Then when you truncate that to fit in a 64 bit value, you are left with all being zero.

---

But let me go into some detail anyway. First, a critique of your C:

```c
// snip. note that i is type double
  printf("print dbl as int: %d\n", i);
```

This line is wrong on two levels: it passes a 64 bit double where printf is expecting a 32 bit int, and it is reinterpret casting those bits to int, which is entirely different than doing a conversion to int.

If you wanted to do this in D, you'd want to explicitly reinterpret the bits using a union or cast through an intermediate pointer. You could even slice off the other 32 bits if you wanted to!

The next line, which uses a proper explicit cast, is written correctly, but still undefined behavior because casting a double to int when it is too large to fit is something neither C nor D (nor the underlying hardware) makes any promises about.

---

And back to D. The `^^` operator in D simply rewrites the expression into `std.math.pow(a, b)`. `std.math.pow` has different implementations for different types. Since both arguments are integral here, it does no floating point calculations at all - it has a pure int/long implementation that works just like multiplication.

So your C comparison isn't quite right because in C, you used `double` and tried to convert, whereas in D, it never touched floating point at all. Integer multiplication is defined to work via two's complement and truncation, and that's exactly what happened here. It overflowed, leaving all zeros in the bits left behind.

Comment: Just a note: the point of the two lines of C which are incorrect are purposefully undefined / incorrect to demonstrate the outcome I was expecting. But, now I understand, so thank you.

Comment: "it is reinterpret casting those bits to int,"  - in C it is *undefined behaviour*. The result (if any) may bear no resemblance to the input, e.g. on common 64-bit systems floating point values are passed to printf using different registers than for integer values